# How can I display html image in a container the same way css displays background-image?

Tags: html, css

So I have this div where I want to display an html image at a dimension of 1200 by 630. The images are usually smaller than the container. If I display the image by using CSS's `background-image, background-size and background-position` then a smaller-sized image gets fitted in the container by scaling up(zoomed in).

This is what I've been trying to achieve by using an image in html. Please note that I can't use `object-fit` because I'll be using this image with a plugin that doesn't support `object-fit` css property.

This is the CSS version:

```css
.outer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 630px;
}

#div {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/dqywpKM.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="div">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML Image version:

```css
.outer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 630px;
}

#div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#img_prev {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="div">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dqywpKM.jpg" id="img_prev" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML image version looks slanted but I have been trying to make it look like a little bit zoomed to fit the container without using `object-fit`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is here the `background-size: cover;`

> Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

-> it tells the image-sizing *make it bigger until it has X- AND Y axis minimum of the container* That means, it makes the image bigger as the container on one of the axis, because it has a different proportion.

You see this in your HTML-image version, the image is stretched.
Give your `#div` an `overflow: hidden;` and `position: relative;`
Now you can add `position: absolute;` to your `#img_prev`.
At this point, the image is cut on the bottom but still not looking zoomed like in your CSS-version.
But there is a way to do this: also add

```
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
```

to your `#img_prev`.
This will center the image inside your div and cut the overflowing edges.

```css
.outer {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 630px;
}

#div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#div2 {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/dqywpKM.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#img_prev {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML-Version</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div id="div">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dqywpKM.jpg" id="img_prev" />
  </div>
</div>
<h2>CSS-Version</h2>
<div class="outer">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div id="div">
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>

        .outer {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 630px;
        }
          
        #div {
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610128114197-485d933885c5?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80');
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried that. Put that code in image. Doesn't work. Then put that in the image parent div. Doesn't work either. I want the zoomed in effect to fit the container just like CSS version.

Comment: use a before element and set its width and height to 100% and its position to absolute. and add this background to the before element. it seems another CSS code is affecting your div. maybe from another file caused by repeated class names or ID.

Comment: Bro, if you don't mind, can you please show me a working example?

Comment: I edited my answer. I just changed the photo. your photo was not loading

Comment: this method is usually used for showing images come and go on page scrolling. if you want just show images(something like Unsplash) you should go with @Atomkind answer or you have to set image width and height the same as div

Comment: Sorry this is not what I wanted. Please read the post again.